# Calculate residue of a complex function

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

I tried to calculate the residue of the complex function 1/z at z=0 in using a contour integral. The contour is a square box of size L that encloses z=0. I used a jupyter notebook using this code:

```
from sympy import *
a, a1, a2, a3 = symbols("a a1 a2 a3", positive=True)
b, b1, b2, b3 = symbols("b b1 b2 b3", positive=True)
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
L = 2
c1 = Curve([t, -L], (t, -L, L))
c2 = Curve([L, t], (t, -L, L))
c3 = Curve([t, L], (t, L, -L))
c4 = Curve([-L, t], (t, L, -L))
I1 = line_integrate(1/(a1+b1*I), c1, [a1, b1])
I2 = line_integrate(1/(a1+b1*I), c2, [a1, b1])
I3 = line_integrate(1/(a1+b1*I), c3, [a1, b1])
I4 = line_integrate(1/(a1+b1*I), c4, [a1, b1])
simplify(I1+I2+I3+I4)
```

and I get the result:

(−1+)

but when I calculate using the residue theorem:

```
2*pi*I*residue(1/x, x, 0)
```

I get:

2

Can someone please point what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think `line_integrate` integrates with respect to arc length. That's not the same thing as a complex line integral, integrating with respect to the complex variable.